# How to ignore .java files when compiling using maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, compilation

I have .java files in my source directory that don't compile yet due to some API change. I would like to fix sources one by one and it would be useful to ignore some of them to run tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the maven compiler plugin and the exclude option:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Point*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Resources:**

- [Maven 2 Compiler plugin - Compile mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

Comment: hi, i tried this.The exclude filter is not working.Suggest plz what could have gone wrong

Comment: In fairness this answer is now three years old, a lot of things happened since.